# Altium: Create custom pad

Tags: altium

I've got this T shaped pad that I've made with 2 fill rectangles. How do I assign a designator to it? I've tried converting to a region and couldn't figure it out that way either. I'm using AD10. Thanks.

[image: Component Footprint]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a pad (can be a small one) and assign an Designator to it (e.g.: 3). When that structure is added to the PCB, the whole area will be connected to "3".

Note that this only works for regions or fills (you'll need to delete any non-fill/region objects which you may have used to create your region --otherwise the non-fill/region objects (e.g. lines) will block you from routing to your pad, as they are not assigned a net when placed onto your PCB).

You could also add multiple pads and assign "3" to each of them to form your T.

Comment: Seems a bit hacky but I guess it sounds like an easy option. Thanks.

Comment: @Cameron Adding a pad within the fill IS Altium's way of doing it. It's not "hacky" at all.

Comment: When I use it in a project it complains about a clearance constraint between the pad and fill. Can I turn that off in the integrated library? Not sure how I'm meant to do it.

Comment: I've actually got 1 out of the 16 components that isn't complaining. My schematic has 8 of them, and they're replicated across an A and B section. Randomly, Q8B is fine and Q8A and all the others are complaining.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot (of your component as well as on the PCB with the problem)? Actually the fill should take on the net of the pad. Are you sure you're using a fill and not a solid region? (also try to use a solid region; maybe I got it wrong)

Comment: Yeah it was a solid region that did it for me. Thanks. All good now.